# SQL based on result from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as below:

```
col1, col2, col3
a,    l1,   v1
a,    l2,   v2
b,    l2,   v3
c,    l3,   v4
```

I need the result with col1 and col3 to be as below:

```
col1, col3
a,    v1
a,    v2
a,    v3
b,    v2
b,    v3
c,    v4
```

meaning get me (all col3 values for col1 = a ) + (col3 values of col2 which belongs to col1 = a)

which translates to (v1,v2) + (v3) = v1,v2,v3 for a.

I am using a PostgresDB to run this. I've tried many methods but not sure how to get the right results efficiently. The actual table has around 1M records.

How do I solve this?

Edit: Apologies for my initial lack in explaining it precisely. basically what I am trying to get is,

values of col1 and col3 in such a way that..

1. get all values of col3 for col1,
   example: for col1 = a, i will have col3 values as v1, v2

Plus

2. col3 values of col2, meaning for col1 = a i have col2 as l1, l2. Hence now i need to get values of col3 where col2 in l1,l2.

I have edited the expected result above.

Comment: Could you take a pass at clarifying your example?  I'm not understanding what you mean by "(col3 values of col2 which belongs to col1 = a)" especially.

Comment: Edited my question to explain the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think you simply want

```
select distinct b.col1, a.col3
from t a
join t b on a.col2=b.col2
```

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gkaxeB32SYWhiuigdN677p/0)**

Comment: Thank u :) it's one of those days where I have completely missed the simple thing.